# How to configure npm-watch?

Tags: npm, watch

I don't know how to configure npm-watch I don't understand how to use it from documentation (readme).

In root project I have script folder with some .js files. After any changes in script folder I want call npm build, how to do this using npm-watch? How to set up npm-watch?

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](https://github.com/M-Zuber/npm-watch) says:

> The keys of the "watch" config should match the names of your "scripts"

It means that in your case the `package.json` file should have:

```
{
  "watch": {
    "build": "script/*.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm build",
    "watch": "npm-watch"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-> Open your project
-> go to terminal 
run the command 
-> npm i watch

then go the package.json
    
    paste the below code 
    
    "watch": {
        "build": "script/*.js"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "build": "npm build",
        "watch": "npm-watch"
      }
     
Last Step 
open the terminal and run the below command 
-> npm run watch
```

[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf4F6.png)